# ICanHaz.js just doesn't work

Tags: javascript, templates, icanhaz.js

From ICanHaz example (slightly modified version of this: http://icanhazjs.com/):

The template:

```
<script id="user" type="text/html">
  <div>
    <p class="name">Hello I'm {{ name }}</p>
    <p><a href="http://twitter.com/{{ twitter }}">@{{ twitter }}</a></p>
  </div>
</script>
```

The code:

```
        var user_data, user;

        user_data = {
            name: "Henrik Joreteg",
            twitter: "HenrikJoreteg",
            employer: "&yet",
            job_title: "JS nerd"
        };

        user = ich.user(user_data, true);
        console.log(user.toString());
```

Console output is:

```
 <div>
        <p class="name">Hello I'm </p>
        <p><a href="http://twitter.com/">@</a></p>
 </div>
```

As you see it reads the template but it doesn't perform substitution. I don't know how to debug it, it's the simplest use case. I see no errors in the console.

Comment: Can you post the code of your template please?

Comment: What's the URL of that example?

Comment: @JaredMcAteer, I modified the example.

Comment: @@Šime Vidas, I modified the example.

Comment: It works for me, see this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NdP6N/1/  are you sure your `user_data` object is the same as what you're showing us?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for any other circumstances when this code may not work properly? Maybe collision with other js libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out the problem was in tag collision between django framework I'm using and ICanHaz.js. The solution is to install django-icanhaz application which not only solves the problem but allows to store icanhaz.js templates as separate files.